# Listar Resultado do Banco por Linhas e Colunas

Tags: php, sql, informix

Estou com o seguinte problema, preciso criar um relatório com dados vindo do banco, listado por linhas e colunas, no formato abaixo:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|          |  01/2020  |  02/2020  |  03/2020  |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  USER_1  |    30%    |    75%    |    63%    |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  USER_2  |    30%    |    50%    |    25%    |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  USER_3  |    30%    |    75%    |    63%    |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Já tenho um while retornando do banco as colunas `periodo, usuario e percentual`

```
$sql = "SELECT periodo,percentual,usuario FROM a1";
$regis = ifx_query($sql,$con);
while($dados = ifx_fetch_row($regis)){
   var_dump($dados);
}
```

O retorno das linhas é simples, mas o das colunas eu não sei como fazer e não conseguir pensar em algo.

Comment: Por acaso suas "colunas" são os conteúdos do campo "periodo" recuperados de sua tabela? Todos os usuários sempre possuem dados para todos os períodos?

Comment: Sim para as duas questões. A coluna vertical é o campo período e as linhas da primeira coluna são os usuários e o miolo são os percentuais.

Comment: Não sei se o Informix implementa pivot tables, se implementar é a solução mais geral. Caso não implemente uma possível solução é uma gambiarra no PHP.

Comment: Dizem que tem, mas não existe nada claro na internet, nem com as pessoas que consultei. Uma questão é que os períodos são dinâmicos e podem mudar de acordo com a seleção do usuário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No fim cheguei a seguinte solução, partindo da sugestão dos comentários acima e buscando por solução de pivot tables:

```
SELECT 
    user,
    max(case when periodo = '92020' then percentual else null end) as mes_9,
    max(case when periodo = '82020' then percentual else null end) as mes_8
FROM a4 group by 1
```